# Mediawiki: Page is in category without linking in code

Tags: mediawiki

Normally pages are assigned to categories if they have a link like `[[Category:example]]` but recently I noticed that we have a new category which is not listed on any pages that are in this category.

So:

- Category site `example` (contains multiple pages)
- looking at the code of one page -> no lik to this category

How is it possible to remove the page from the category if no link to the category exists in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

The category could be included though a template. Try removing templates that are on the page one by one to see which one adds the category. Then edit the code of that template if you want to keep the template, but remove the category.